# jQuery / IE10 - SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'data'

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

jQuery `.data()` seems to be broken on IE10.

The below code works fine with Chrome and FF but trigger an error

> SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method data

in IE10.

Any idea why / how to have it working under IE10 ?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('body').on("click", ".clickme", function(){
       parent = $(this).parents(".container");
       html = $(parent.data('my-target')).html();
       $('#result').html(html);
   });           
});
```

```css
#result {
    margin: 15px;
}

#second, #fourth {
    display: none;
}

.clickme {
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script><div class="container" data-my-target="#second">
    <div class="clickme" id="first">Click me</div>
    <div id="second">Hello World</div>
</div>
<div class="container" data-my-target="#fourth">
    <div class="clickme" id="third">Cliquez-moi</div>
    <div id="fourth">Bonjour !</div>
</div>
<div id="result">
    
</div>
```

See it on jsbin : http://jsbin.com/hovuwequvu/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`parent` is a poor (implicitly global) variable name. It's conflicting with `window.parent` property:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('body').on("click", ".clickme", function(){
       parent = $(this).parents(".container");
   //  ^^ You are attempting to write to the window.parent property here
       html = $(parent.data('my-target')).html();
       $('#result').html(html);
   });           
});
```

Change it to a more appropriate name and also declare it as a variable:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('body').on("click", ".clickme", function(){
       var parentContainer = $(this).parents(".container");
       var html = $(parentContainer.data('my-target')).html();
       $('#result').html(html);
   });           
});
```

Comment: If you used 'use strict' in your code then you will get an error 'undeclared variable'.

Comment: I changed the variable name and it now works like a charm. Thanks !